# Issue Where Array is Limited to One Item At Any Given Time

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

I am running into an issue in a rather simple function that builds an array - and I'm drawing a blank on what the issue is. It's likely something simple - but I'm just not seeing it.

Here's the function:

```
private onSelection(selection)
{
    if (selection)
    {
        const selectionsArray = [];
        selectionsArray.push(selection);
        console.log(selectionsArray);
        console.log(selectionsArray.length);
        return selectionsArray;
    }
}
```

And the "selection" is being passed via a checkbox, like so:

```
<md-checkbox (click)="onSelection('A')">A</md-checkbox>
<md-checkbox (click)="onSelection('B')">B</md-checkbox>
<md-checkbox (click)="onSelection('C')">C</md-checkbox>
```

Right now regardless of what's clicked on in the checkboxes, my array is always just one item, and this is confirmed when I console out the length - which is always 1. What am I missing here? Why won't the array build into 2 and 3 items as multiple selections are pushed?

Comment: `const selectionsArray = [];`, you're making a *new*, blank array everytime you click on one of these elements.

Comment: But don't I need to initialize the array at some point?

Comment: const selectionsArray = []; assign it outside the function @Ademo

Comment: Ah, thanks. Of course.

Answer (score 2):

Your **onSelection** handler always reset the existing array before adding 
the selected element. so you need to initialize your array outside of 
your **onSelection** function.

**suggestion:-**
you can remove the **if (selection)** condition cause in your existing code, it'll always be true but you should check if a selected element is already in your **selectionsArray** before adding and in this way you won't get any duplicate entry in your **selectionsArray**. btw you should remove the **const** declaration of your **selectionsArray**, it doesn't make any sense.

```
const selectionsArray = [];
private onSelection(selection)
{
  if (selection)
  {
    selectionsArray.push(selection);
    console.log(selectionsArray);
    console.log(selectionsArray.length);
    return selectionsArray;
  }
}
```